# postfix rate limiting

Tags: postfix, rate-limiting

I did add a new slow transport to my Postfix configuration but this doesn't looks to work. Messages pass correctly in the slow transport but they aren't rate-limited.

Currently, I've been setting this up in my master.cf:

```
slow      unix  -       -       n       -       1       smtp
  -o default_destination_concurrency_limit=1
  -o initial_destination_concurrency=1
  -o smtp_destination_concurrency_limit=1
  -o in_flow_delay=2s
  -o syslog_name=slow
```

Any idea why my messages aren't rate-limited?

Comment: Are you trying to throttle inbound or outbound messages?  Also the output of `postconf -n` and your Postfix version would be helpful.

Comment: Also, how many messages are you attempting to deliver?  And how are they injected?  Different limits kick in depending on various concurrency issues.

Comment: I'm trying to limit outbound messages that might be created either by mail command or by the perl mime lite (script) library.

The number of messages shouldn't be much that something like 10 per sec, under heavy usage. But this isn't normal situation, normal is 0 per second.I'm running Postfix 2.5.5 and postconf -n is: http://pastebin.com/isJtT0fM Thanks for your help!

Comment: And what is in `/etc/postfix/transport`?

Comment: destination.net     slow: 
And it pass correctly in the slow transport but not rate limited (I can see in the logs postfix/slow).

Comment: And do you want all outbound SMTP traffic to be rate-limited or only to specific destinations?

Comment: only to destination.net

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The config you have now is only going to make sure you only have a single simultaneous delivery to each destination.  It's not going to actually throttle anything.  I think adding this line to `main.cf` may accomplish what you want:

```
slow_destination_rate_delay=2s
```

That will tell the queue manager to insert the specified delay between each individual delivery to the same destination.  Since you haven't modified `default_destination_recipient_limit` from its default, it should apply the delay to each recipient domain.  So this should mandate a 2 second delay between each delivery to the domain listed in the transport map.

When I've had to do this in the past, I didn't go with the alternate transport mechanism.  Since I was only concerned with delivery speed to each unique domain, I just added these lines to `main.cf`:

```
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
smtp_destination_rate_delay = 1s
```

So if there is mail being injected for 30 different domains, it may try to deliver a message to all 30 of them at once, but never more than one at a time to `example.com` and never faster than 1 per second to `example.com`.

Comment: Can I also put everything under the master.cf like this?
slow      unix  -       -       n       -       1       smtp
    -o smtp_destination_concurrency_limit=1
    -o smtp_destination_rate_delay=2s
    -o slow_destination_rate_delay=2s
    -o default_destination_concurrency_limit=1
    -o initial_destination_concurrency=1
    -o in_flow_delay=2s
    -o syslog_name=slow

Comment: I think that should work; I haven't used that technique though, so I can't say for sure.